# Critical damping and mathematical requirement of 2 constants

Tags: friction, harmonic-oscillator, oscillators

The general equation of an oscillator with a damping term $-rv$, where $r$ is damping coeffeciet and $v$ is velocity is

$$x=e^{-pt}(Ae^{qt}+Be^{-qt})$$

where $p=r/2m$ and $q=\sqrt{p^2-s/m}$, $s$ is Hooke's constant, $m$ is mass and $t$ is time

Now I don't understand why we physically cannot have $q=0$. Almost every author says that because then we will only have a single constant to worry about which goes against the theory of differential equations, sure, but in an ideal world experiment I always can make $q=0$. So how to reconsile this with the fact that we must have two constants, without claiming that $q\neq 0 $ but $q\approx0$ is permissible so Taylor expand it?

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. You can certainly set $q=0$. If so, you must solve the differential eq'n using a different method, and the result is a non-oscillatory function. The same thing happens with the differential equation $y'' = -\alpha^2y$. If $\alpha\neq0$, then we get oscillatory solutions ($y=A\cos(\alpha x) + B\sin(\alpha x)$), but if $\alpha=0$, then $y= A x +B$. The point is, *qualitatively* different features arise at (and on either side of ($q=0$), and this manifests as a sort of *discontinuity* in the solution set that doesn't allow you to take the limit $q\to0$.

Comment: @march This makes so much sense, thank you very much. This sought of thing was never mentioned to me, at least in my college class, or in Books by French and Pain. Can you please expand a bit more on this?

Comment: you can have $q=0$. The problem there is that you need to find 2 independent solutions of the  2nd order ODE to get the most general solution: it turns out that those solutions are $e^{pt}$ and $t \, e^{pt}$

Comment: @basics I see, thank you

Comment: If you want some more details about the reason why you get those solutions for (n-th order) linear ODEs, you can have a look at these hand-written notes https://basics.altervista.org/test/Math/ode/linear_ode_n.html Feel free to ask

Comment: @basics thank you, thats a great help